# Handle GZip compression on Apache 2.4.18 using mod_jk

Tags: apache, gzip, reverse-proxy, deflate

I use Apache 2.4.18 as a reverse proxy to a Java web application.

I need to configure gzip-compression on Html and Javascript files.

I have deflate, headers and filter modules activated (and mod_jk, for sure).

My apache2.conf file is a the default configuration file where I've added:

```
Include sites-enabled/
JKWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
ServerName localhost
```

My sites-enabled/example.com is reverse proxying to my application like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName gzip.example.com
    SSLEngine on

    JKMount /application* 172_10_0_1;use_server_errors=400,500

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gzip.example.com-error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gzip.example.com-access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/*.example.com.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/private/chain_example.com.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

And I'm using, in the mods-enabled/deflate.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        <IfModule mod_filter.c>
                # these are known to be safe with MSIE 6
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml

                # everything else may cause problems with MSIE 6
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
                AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

My browser says, on a js file (also check with Google Pagespeed):

```
Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:15292
Content-Type:text/javascript
Date:Fri, 22 Jan 2016 16:21:05 GMT
ETag:W/"15292-1440752026000"
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Fri, 28 Aug 2015 08:53:46 GMT
Pragma:No-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_jk/1.2.37 OpenSSL/1.0.2e
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Is there a configuration that I missed?

Comment: Are the two modules in the IfModule actually loaded?

Comment: @covener Checked a last time, yes they are.